# Este código é adequado ou uma má prática?

Tags: c#

Boa tarde, sou iniciante em programação e no caso meu problema seria com C# e Windows Forms. Tenho uma tela para relatórios de um sistema de PDV, e nesse relatório posso selecionar as opções diário, mensal e anual (a escolha é feita através de um `ComboBox`). Porém, para cada uma dessas opções também tenho 'sub-opções', como por exemplo, os relatórios do tipo mensal podem ser pra listar quanto foi vendido de cada produto, ou para listar todas as vendas, por exemplo (essa escolha também é feita através de um `CombobBox`), dados esses que serão lançados em uma `DataGridView`.
De início, comecei por utilizar vários 'ifs', contudo isso resultou em cadeia enorme de laços de seleção. Algo assim:

```
if(cbxTime.SelectedIndex == 0)//Relatório diário
{
    if(cbxSubOption.SelectedIndex == 0)//Relatório diário de produtos
    {
        //Pesquisava no banco e jogava dentro de uma DataGridView
    }
    else if(cbxSubOption.SelectedIndex == 1)//Relatório diário de vendas
    {
        //Pesquisava no banco e jogava dentro de uma DataGridView
    }
    else
    {  }
}
else if(cbxTime.SelectedIndex == 1)//Relatórios mensais
{
    //uma cadeia de ifs semelhante à do primeiro if.
}
else//Relatórios Anuais
{  }
```

Como eu não achei muito viável, tentei trocar essa solução por algo mais dinâmico, mas não sei se foi correto. Minha ideia foi criar um vetor de `Dictionary`, mais especificamente um vetor de três posições, cada uma representando uma das faixas de tempo. Cada `Dictionary` era composto por um index que seria o index da sub-Combobox e por um `action`, uma referência para uma função sem retorno que executaria o código que eu precisasse.
Assim eu criei uma função para cada uma das possíveis combinações de `ComboBox` e joguei nessa variável. Dentro de cada uma delas, eu realizava as ações necessárias para jogar os dados na `DataGridView`, algo mais ou menos assim:

```
private Dictionary<int, Action>[] dataGridActions;

public void Form1()//No construtor
{
    dataGridActions = new Dictionary<int, Action>[3]
        {
            new Dictionary<int, Action>()
            {
                { 0, ListDailyProducts},
                { 1, ListDailySales},
                { 2, x},
            },
            new Dictionary<int, Action>()
            {
                { 0, x},
                { 1, x},
                { 2, x},
            },
            new Dictionary<int, Action>()
            {
                { 0, x},
                { 1, x},
                { 2, x},
            },
        };
}

private void ListDailySales()
{
    //Fazia a devida ação
}
private void ListDailyProducts()
{
    //Fazia a devida ação
}
```

Na hora de invocar:

```
int time = cbxTime.SelectedIndex;
int option = cbxSubOption.SelectedIndex;
gridActions[time][option].Invoke();
```

Está funcionando tudo perfeitamente, mas a questão é, é correto o que fiz aqui? Tudo isso se encontra apenas no form. Eu meio que dei uma lida sobre `Strategy` para tentar fazer, mas sei muito bem que não usei nada disso muito na prática. Gostaria de saber se existe um jeito mais correto de se fazer, e onde devo buscar soluções para casos como esse no futuro, muito obrigado desde já.

Comment: Seria interessante você criar `Enums` para esses valores fixos que está usando na sua lógica. Assim quem olhar o código vai poder compreender melhor o que está escrito.

Comment: Obrigado @LeandroAngelo, vou fazer isso